# The deployment on android simulator is very slow

Tags: xamarin.android

when deploying an app built with xamarin on any stock android simulator from visual studio 2013, first deployment takes more than 4 minutes. These boxes are checked: use shared runtime, use fast deployment.

On a real device, the same 1st deployment take seconds.

I've checked PC resources, and CPU is at 20%, all other monitors are at 1% (SSD, 16Go ram, ...). I disabled antivirus and firewalls.

Are there any way to speed up deployment on android simulator ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using genymotion, it seems faster than normal emulator. Give it a try if you can.